# How to interact with a join table in bookshelf and knex?

Tags: mysql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I want to create an entry in a join table using bookshelf. I followed the instructions on the bookshelf website [here](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Associations-many-to-many). (Models instantiation with bookshelf and tables creation with knex).

Is there a way, upon creation of a new Book, to add values to the authors_books table WITHOUT creating an authors_books model/collection?

What should I add to this:

```
//Books references the Books collection that holds the Book models

var book = new Book({
      title: title,
      base_url: req.headers.origin
    });

    book.save().then(function(newBook) {
      Books.add(newLink);
      res.send(200, newBook);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, it's quite simple.

You need two models, Book and Author. Both have `belongsToMany` relationship defined and `withPivot` as well. `withPivot` lists the attributes that are in the junction table, see more here: [http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-withPivot](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-withPivot)

Afterwards, you call `updatePivot`, to update the attributes that are in `author_book` table only.